# Google People Api Contact is created but I can't see it anywhere

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I'm using PeopleService in order to create contacts straight into my G Suit Account. I followed the security steps about getting the key for a type of Service Account. My Application will create contacts so that there's no need to request a specific user permission. It has its own key and credentials.
My code seems  to work except because the CreateContactRequest provides me ResourceName with value "people/c171255166120767303". And every time I request I got a different resourceName like this "people/c9013378989213012841". 
The problem is, where the hell that goes? At my G Suite account, I can’t see the created contact anywhere.
But the resulting Person object seems to be ok.

How can I check if this works? Where the contact was created?

The code is as bellow:

```
    private static string _clientId = "1........1";
    private static string _clienteScret = "i******************_";
    private static string _serviceAccountId = "aaaa@bbbb.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
```

public static void Cadastrar(Models.SignupRequest message)
        {

```
        var chave =
            @"D:\********.p12";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(chave, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(_serviceAccountId)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { 
                    PeopleService.Scope.Contacts, 
                    PeopleService.Scope.ContactsReadonly,
                    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
                }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Client for www",
        });

        var contactToCreate = new Person();
        var names = new List<Name> {new Name() {GivenName = message.name, FamilyName = "Doe"}};

        contactToCreate.Names = names;
        contactToCreate.EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>
        {
            new EmailAddress()
            {
                DisplayName = message.name,
                Value = message.email
            }
        };
        contactToCreate.Organizations = new List<Organization>
        {
            new Organization()
            {
                Current = true,
                Name = message.nome_fantasia,
            }
        };
        contactToCreate.Biographies = new List<Biography>
        {
            new Biography()
            {
                Value = message.ToString()
            }
        };

        contactToCreate.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>
        {
            new PhoneNumber()
            {
                Type = "mobile",
                Value = message.celular
            },
            new PhoneNumber()
            {
                Type = "work",
                Value = message.telefone
            }
        };

        var request = new Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest(service, contactToCreate);

        var createdContact = request.Execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create contact for user with 'email@yourdomain.com' through a service account you need:

- Use "setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)" to impersonate the user
- Enable impersonation on your G-Suite for People API service. For this point:

  - See section "Delegating domain wide access" [here](https://damon.ghost.io/using-service-account-to-act-on-behalf-of-your-google-apps-users/)
  - Get client-id from your credential account
  - Use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts" as scope.